# Turn date in email into link which when clicked adds item to calendar

Tags: iphone, email, mobile, gmail, html-email

I have a date in an email but the Gmail app on my iPhone doesn't recognise it such that it can be clicked on to add it to the phone's calendar. Is there some way that I can mark it such that this is possible?

I have already done something similar for phone numbers...

```
<a href='tel:012345678'>012345678</a>
```

This works great.

Comment: I think writing it out in full should do.

Comment: This, for example, isn't working... "Calendar: 16:00-20:00, 17th November 2016"

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps just one hour, as in not hour-hour.

Comment: No effect in Gmail.